# How persist using XMLParse with JPA

Tags: java, xml, database, jpa

I have an XML Parse as the example I picked up on the internet of channel codeur java:

```
public class Example{

public void getParserXML(String f){
```

Obtain and configure a SAX basead parser

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
```

Obtain object for SAX parser

```
SAXParser saxp = null;
try {
     saxp = factory.newSAXParser();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(Example.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SAXException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(Example.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Default handler for SAX handler class
all three methos are written in handler's body

```
    DefaultHandler handler;
    handler = new DefaultHandler(){
    boolean bnamePerson = false;
    boolean bagePerson = false;

    String namePerson, agePerson;

    PersonEntity personEnt = new PersonEntity();
    CallPersist callPer = new CallPersist();
```

This method is called every time the parser gets an open tag '<'
identifies which tag is being open at time by assingning an open flag

```
Public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException{
    if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("namePerson")){
       bnamePerson = true;
      }
    if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("agePerson")){
       bagePerson = true;
      }                
    }            

Public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException{

        }
```

Print data stored in between '<' and '>' tags

```
Public void characters(char ch[], int start, int lenght)throws SAXException{

    if(bnamePerson){                    
       System.out.println("Name Person is "+new String(ch, start, lenght));
       namePerson = new String(ch, start, lenght); 
       personEnt.setName(namePerson);
       bnamePerson = false;
    }
    if(bagePerson){
       System.out.println("Age is "+new String(ch, start, lenght));
       agePerson = new String(ch, start, lenght); 
       personEnt.setAge(agePerson);
       bagePerson = false;
    }  
       callPer.persistPerson(personEnt); 
    }     
    }; 

    try {
        saxp.parse(f, handler);
    } catch (SAXException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Example.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Example.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

The function CallPersist just have this:

```
public void persistPerson(PersonEntity personEnt){
    EntityManager em = EntityManagerHelper.getEntityManager();

    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.persist(personEnt);
    em.clear();

    em.close(); 

    }
```

Notes:

- For JPA does not returnner an Atomicity error, I put the ID manually.
- The programm execute normal, but the data not are persists.

What the way right for resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the transaction calls are wrong.

It should be:

```
public void persistPerson(PersonEntity personEnt){
    EntityManager em = EntityManagerHelper.getEntityManager();

    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(personEnt);
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    em.clear();
    em.close(); 
}
```

Comment: Wow, what a rude mistake I was blind. Thank you very much. I had never used ParseXML and thought I was putting the call in the wrong place.